# add image to twitter share intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, android-file

I'm trying to add an image to my twitter share intent. I save an image locally in one class and then in another I get the image and try to attach to my intent.

Here is my code

```
private void shareTwitter(){

    try {

        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = getActivity().openFileInput("photo.jpg");
        Bitmap shot = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        File file = new File(MapView.path, "snapshot.jpg");
        if(file.exists()){
            Log.i("FILE", "YES");
        }else{
            Log.i("FILE", "NO");
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.gobaby.app/drawable/back");             
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("/*");
            intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Thiws is a share message");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(intent);            

    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

At the moment there is no exception in my logcat my app just displays a toast saying image failed to load.

Please what an I doing wrong?

Comment: Run through a `debug run` step by step, and check your variables.

Comment: which variable should I be checking? for starters is this the correct approach? I've checked to see if the file is found and it is.

Comment: Have you been able to successfully save anything to twitter?

Comment: as of May 2014 this approach is not working :(

Comment: @agamov, do you know the solution since May 2014 ?

Comment: @Seb83 added my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you need

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: i have already twitter app, then also it goes to catch **"You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device"**

Answer (score 7):

This might be helpful for somebody:

```
private void sendShareTwit() {
    try {
        Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        String filename = "twitter_image.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.twitter_share_text));
        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean resolved = false;
        for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
            if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("twitter")) {
                tweetIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
                        ri.activityInfo.name);
                resolved = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        startActivity(resolved ?
                tweetIntent :
                Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Choose one"));
    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
private fun shareOnTwitter() {
    val file = File(context!!.filesDir, FILENAME_SHARE_ON_TWITTER)
    val uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, com.yourpackage.activity.YourActivity, file)

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "image/jpeg"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriForFile)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```