# Share image, text via Twitter native app

Tags: android, twitter, share

I am trying to share image and text via native twitter app if its installed on phone.

If the user have installed native twitter app, open the native twitter app else show toast msg.

Please let me know is that any other solutions that i can use or modify the below sol to work.

I have search for few things and tried it :

**Sol 1**

```
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a Test.");
        tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");

        PackageManager packManager = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent,  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        boolean resolved = false;
        for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo: resolvedInfoList){
            if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.twitter.android")){
                tweetIntent.setClassName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, 
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name );
                resolved = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(resolved){
            activity.startActivity(tweetIntent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Twitter app isn't found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

it will not open the app, even if i have the native twitter app installed.

**Sol 2**

```
Intent tweet_in_native_app = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://post?message=hi ....")); 
activity.startActivity(tweet_in_native_app);
```

it allows only to post text, i have to post image and url as well

**Sol 3**

```
String originalMessage = "This is just a sample text";

        String originalMessageEscaped = null;
        try {
           originalMessageEscaped = String.format(
            "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(originalMessage, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(originalMessageEscaped != null) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           i.setData(Uri.parse(originalMessageEscaped));
           activity.startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
           // Some Error
        }
```

Here it will prompt the list of apps along with the Browser and Twitter, i want it to directly open the app if its installed rather than asking the user.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120036/add-image-to-twitter-share-intent-android